# Can't configure access between applications in Azure Active Directory

Tags: authentication, visual-studio-2013, azure-active-directory

I use Windows Azure Active Directory to secure my WebAPI. But the problem is that I don't see my application in a list of available applications.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create New MVC WebAPI project with Organizational Authentication option. Specify Azure Domain and logged-in successfully. Project created!
2. Go to Azure Manage Portal -> Active Directory -> Specific Domain -> Applications. Can see my newly created WebAPI application in the list.
3. Add New Application to the Active Directory (tried both: Native and Web Site). Specify all required fields like Name, Redirect URL etc. and go to configuration.
4. In Application Configuration page try to allow access to other Web APIs. But my WebAPI application (created in step 1 and verified in the list of applications in step 2 ) is not in the list of available WebAPIs. Actually only two options available there: a) **Windows Azure Active Directory**; 2) **Windows Azure Service Management API**;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the team in integrating a much richer experience at the moment, this feature seems to be broken if you follow most tutorials.  The good news is it is still entirely possible! albeit a wee bit more confounding to get working.  Follow [this guidance from Dan Kershaw](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/2b03b3c8-47ab-458e-9872-cfd4bc5b678b/granting-native-application-access-to-web-application?forum=WindowsAzureAD).

In short.

1. Download the app manifest
2. Edit the app manifest
3. Upload the app manifest
4. Update your relying app's configuration to require the desired consents of the directory.

Comment: Happy to help, sad to see your experience is so hampered.

Comment: As of now even the linked article is out of date and this didn't work for me.